# Is there an issue using two types of tables engine into one database

Tags: mysql

I have one database with wordpress and other site installed into it, they uses same database but since the wordpress table engine is INNODB and my site is using MyISAM. Is there an issue with diff. table engine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not a problem having tables with different table engines - not even in the same schema.

MyISAM is good for tables that are heavily read. InnoDB is good for tables that are heavily inserted/updated to, because it supports row-level locking. (MyISAM locks the whole table.) InnoDB also has foreign key contraints, which MyISAM does not. I could go on...

The only drawback I can think of is to that you have to manage more database settings in the MySQL configuration file (my.cnf). InnoDB and MyISAM have different setttings, like innodb_buffer_pool_size (for InnoDB) and key_buffer_size (for MyISAM).

Answer (score 0):

MyISAM and InnoDB have different properties, but using them together should not be an issue. You may need to do a little more legwork when it comes to tuning your database configuration a little more (InnoDB has it's own set of configuration variables).